# "wire' in "Understand That People Are Wired Very Differently"

Tags: meaning

I am reading book "Principles: Life and Work" by Ray Dalio

In chapter 4 of Part II, Understand That People Are **Wired** Very Differently,
“Because of the different ways that our brains are **wired**, we all experience reality in different ways and any single way is essentially distorted. This is something that we need to acknowledge and deal with. So if you want to know what is true and what to do about it, you must understand your own brain.
”

I am unable to grasp the meaning of 'wired' here.

[Wire](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wire) is defined as a verb in OED as:

1. Install electric circuits or wires in.
2. Provide, fasten, or reinforce with wires.
3. Send a telegram or cablegram to.
4. Snare (an animal) with wire.
5. Obstruct (a ball, shot, or player) by a hoop.

I find none of them fit the context.

How to understand the 'wire' here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OED definition #1 is the definition you are looking for.

The context is that a complex computer or electrical machine is wired to perform a task.  Changing the wiring changes the function of the computer or machine.

This makes more sense when you remember the history of computers.  Today we have integrated circuits on soldered boards.  In the beginning there were wires.  Miles of wires.  And the wires were quite literally moved around to change the function or abilities of the machine.

Thus, to say, "people are wired differently" you are using the action of changing the function of a complex machine by changing its wiring as a metaphor to describe the fact that people have differences in their behavior, despite all of us being the same thing: a human being.